# Do I need to lock before setting some bucket in redisson?

Tags: java, redisson

If I want to set a bucket in Redisson, do I need to prevent race condition by incorporating `Redisson.getLock()`? Or `RBucket.set()` does that internally?

In general, other than application requirements, is there any scenario that I need to surround a block by locks before setting / getting something to / from Redisson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use Lock with Bucket object, because all redis/redisson operations are atomic.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference too?

Comment: @Mehran https://redis.io/commands/eval `Atomicity of scripts` section. Redisson uses lot of lua scripts. Redis is single-threaded process. Thus, only one command could be executed concurrently.

Comment: @Mehran here is bucket object usage examples https://github.com/redisson/redisson-examples/blob/master/objects-examples/src/main/java/org/redisson/example/objects/BucketExamples.java